# trouble splitting strings - asp.net VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a big database where each row has a unique document code and then a price per quantity and per member/non member. i.e. each quantity has 2 prices a member price and a non member price. (Would post a pic but apparently i don't have enough reputation).

Anyway i rip the values from the database using a select command that looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="sds_docReader" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
 runat="server" SelectCommand="
 SELECT '--Please Select--' AS fld_DocCode, '' AS myValue,  0 as myorder
 UNION
 SELECT fld_DocCode, (CAST([fld_MemCost25] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost25] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost50] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost50] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost75] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost75] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost100] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost100] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost200] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost200] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost300] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost300] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost400] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost400] AS varchar(10)) + '@@' + CAST([fld_MemCost500] AS varchar(10)) + '^^' + CAST([fld_NonMemCost500] AS varchar(10))) AS myValue, 
 1 as myorder
 FROM [tbl_DocData]
 ORDER BY myorder, fld_DocCode " />
```

and shove it into the value field of my dropdown list to get something like this on the page back-end:

`value="60.50^^75.50@@121.00^^151.00@@135.75^^181.50@@181.00^^242.00@@362.00^^484.00@@453.00^^633.00@@484.00^^724.00@@605.00^^905.00"`

So this is what i'm trying to do at the moment:

Split the value field at every @@ to get an array of price pairs:
`"[member_price]^^[non_memberprice]"`

Using the `.selectedindex` from a quantity drop down list i pull out the right pair from the array I've just made.

then the final step is to split the price pair array from `price1^^price2` into an array of `price1, price2`

then depending on whether they have checked a box to show they are a member or not i'll take either the 0 index member of the array (what was on the left hand side of the price pair) for the member price, or the 1 index member of the array for the non member price.

this is the code i'm trying to use to do the above:

```
Protected Sub btn_Calc_Command(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
    'get the left side of the price pairs (members)
    Dim side As Integer = 0

    If cb_CCTAMember.Checked = True Then
        'get the right side (non members)
        side = 1
    End If


    If AC1.SelectedItem.Text <> "--Please Select--" And Quan1.SelectedItem.Text <> "0" Then
        'we calculate

        'get right hidden value string
        Dim costs As String = AC1.SelectedItem.Value

        'split by quantity to get price pairs
        Dim costarray As Array
        costarray = costs.Split("@@")

        'get right pair
        Dim pair As String = costarray(Quan1.SelectedIndex - 1)

        'split the pair
        Dim sprice As Array
        sprice = pair.Split("^^")

        'show cost as the right value
        Cost1.Value = sprice(side)

    End If
End Sub
```

So at the moment it works, but only for every other value. I.e. it will work for 25 but not for 50, will work for 75 but not for 100.

Am i missing anything obvious/ any ideas on what could be going wrong/ thoughts on alternative ways to get the same result.

cheers

Comment: The only thing that I can see as incorrect is the `Quan1.SelectedIndex -1`. The index starts at zero like the array index, so no need to subtract 1

Comment: I did that because i gave that DDL a default value of 0, so 25 would have an index location of 1 in the DDL but would refer to the 0th member of the array created by splitting the value= string. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Now it is clear, but then I don't see any error. If you select 50 in the Quan1 DDL you get the index 1 in the costarray and this should be correctly point to the pair `121.00^^151.00`.

Comment: Why are you shoving the entire string into each value for each `ListItem`?  Why not simply store the member/non-member price in the proper quantity field?  You can still have your default `ListItem` (just set the `AppendDataBoundItems` attribute to true and explicitly declare the first `ListItem` in your markup).

Comment: Also, what is `AC1`?  I'm guessing `Quan1` is the quantity drop down list.

Comment: AC1 = agreement code 1 i.e. the name of the first drop down list. As for the second part of your question i'm not entirely sure, i asked my boss for some help and he came up with this. Now we're trying to fix it. I'll pass on your comment though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not do the trick, but try replacing both your `string.split()` to:

```
costs.Split({"@@"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

and

```
pair.Split({"^^"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I'm guessing you're having the issue with it working for odd numbers due to the fact that the split() function is keeping in empty entries...

Like I said, it may not do the trick, but I've had similar issues fixed with things like this before...